# Nested If Statment Formula field for Text fields

Tags: formula, nested

Hi I am trying to create a formula field that will provide a geography field based on the value of one or more fields. I  currently get the followign error

Error:

> Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3,
>   received 2

Formula

```
IF(
AND(
OppRegion__c = "EMEA",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Azerbaijan","Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Bahrain", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Iraq", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Israel", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Jordan", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Kuwait", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Lebanon", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Palestine", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Qatar", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Saudi Arabia", "Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "Turkey", "Middle East",
If(Account_Country__c = "Russia", "Russia",
If(Account_Country__c = "Russian Federation","Russia",
If(Account_Country__c = "UAE","Middle East",
If(Account_Country__c = "United Arab Emirates","Middle East",
IF(Account_Country__c = "yemen", "Middle East"),
If(
AND(
OppRegion__c = "APAC",
IF(
CONTAINS(
Account_Country__c, "China"),"China",
If(Account_Country__c = "Japan","Japan",
If(Account_Country__c = "JP","Japan",
If(Account_Country__c = "Macau","China",
If(Account_Country__c = "Vietnam","Vietnam",
If(Account_Country__c = "KR","South Korea",
If(
CONTAINS(
Account_Country__c, "Korea","South Korea"),
IF(
OppRegion__c = "NAM", "North America",
IF(OppRegion__c = "ROW", "SOUTH AMERICA","Other"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Problem is described by the error, you have not provided enough parameters to one or more IF statement(s) in there somewhere. Use a text editor and break them out ensuring each IF contains a value test, and true part, and a false part.

Comment: Formulas like this case be made a bit easier to understand and a bit shorter by using the [CASE function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF( 
AND( OppRegion__c = "EMEA", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Azerbaijan","Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Bahrain", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Iraq", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Israel", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Jordan", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Kuwait", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Lebanon", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Palestine", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Qatar", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Saudi Arabia", "Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "Turkey", "Middle East", 
If(Account_Country__c = "Russia", "Russia", 
If(Account_Country__c = "Russian Federation","Russia", 
If(Account_Country__c = "UAE","Middle East", 
If(Account_Country__c = "United Arab Emirates","Middle East", 
IF(Account_Country__c = "yemen", "Middle East"), 
If( AND( OppRegion__c = "APAC", 
IF( CONTAINS( Account_Country__c, "China"),"China", 
If(Account_Country__c = "Japan","Japan", 
If(Account_Country__c = "JP","Japan", 
If(Account_Country__c = "Macau","China", 
If(Account_Country__c = "Vietnam","Vietnam", 
If(Account_Country__c = "KR","South Korea", 
If( CONTAINS( Account_Country__c, "Korea","South Korea"), 
IF( OppRegion__c = "NAM", "North America", 
IF(OppRegion__c = "ROW", "SOUTH AMERICA","Other"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

I think the problem is in `IF(Account_Country__c = "yemen", "Middle East")` where only two parameters are passed. Remove the closing `)`